4G modems allowing to set a higher TX output power
Does anyone know of a Linux-compatible 4G/LTE modem (USB stick or otherwise) which allows setting a higher TX output power that the standard +23dbm?

I’m voting to close this question because this isn't about lInux/UNIX at all – it's about buying hardware.

Higher TX power alone isn't usually going to fix a poor two-way radio connection; you would need a more sensitive receiver too. Also, operating a stronger-than-standard transmitter on the 4G bands will often require a special permit. A higher-gain antenna (directional one if possible) will help in both transmit and receive directions, and may be more acceptable regulation-wise than a boosted transmitter.
